# Merging results from two database tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two database tables, both contain a column called 'direction' and one contains a foreign key to the other. I would like to query the database once to give me a merged result set of rows which contain all the data from both tables.

For a row(s) in the first table, there is no guarantee that there will be complimentary entries in the second table. In this case, I'd just like the cell to be blank.

Extracted examples of the two tables are shown below

```
Table 1
case_id   direction   speed
1         000         1.22
1         090         0.97
1         180         0.17
1         270         2.50
2                     2.14

Table 2
tbl1_case_id   direction   probability
1              000         0.175
1              090         0.275
1              180         0.555
1              270         0.145
```

Would I would like is a result set as follows:

```
Results
case_id   direction   speed   probability
1         000         1.22    0.175
1         090         0.97    0.275
1         180         0.17    0.555
1         270         2.50    0.145
2                     2.14
```

Is there an efficient SQL query which will allow me to produce this?

Comment: Your cell is not blank for direction 330.  I'm confused.  And if you want all rows from both tables, why don't you have 270?

Comment: That's a typo. Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all rows from both tables, then use `full join`:

```
select id, direction, t1.speed, t2.probability
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (id, direction);
```

Your sample results and explanation suggest a `left join`:

```
select id, direction, t1.speed, t2.probability
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     using (id, direction);
```

However, the value for 330 would be blank in this case.

Comment: Thanks this works well. The 330 was an error in my original post. I've updated it. And yes, you're right, the left join is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a simple left join -

```
SELECT T1.case_id, T1.direction, T1.speed, T2.probability
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.id
```